# Recommended/Optimal way of obtaining a value online, doing something in a local program, then uploading-editing the online value to something else

Tags: java, xml, synchronization

I have a general strategy question,

I've got a Java program that posts to a Facebook Page of mine. The program was insofar used by a single user, pulling from a single database. No synchronisation needed.

Recently, the need arose for a total of three users to use the same program, every instance of it locally, to post to the **same** Facebook page, pulling from the **same** database. To avoid duplicate postings or other conflicts between postings, it is time to find a way to synchronize.

One way is to, simply, **only allow one user to use the program at a time**.

---

I have no previous experience with this, and I'm thinking something along the lines of this:

1. I maintain a personal website. I could put an XML document up somewhere, that will store a single value, for example:

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <inUse>FALSE</inUse>`
2. If the local instance of the program reads `inUse == false`, it sets the online value to `true`, does its work, then before exiting edits it again to `false`.
3. If it reads `inUse == true`, it notifies the user and disables its interface so the user cannot do anything.

---

I know that my idea is probably lightyears away from an optimal solution. I say again that this is the first time I deal with something like synchronizing multiple remote instances of a program. I know XML is supposed to be read, not to be edited, and removing/re-uploading XML data through Java seems crude and barbaric.

What would be a good way of tackling this?

Comment: Do you have a server? What sort of conflicts are you trying to avoid? Why would use an XML file when you have a database?

Comment: There will probably be no hard or programatic conflicts from the database itself. It's just, since the programs are asynchronized and are pulling text from the same database, our recipient (the Facebook Page) could end up with two of the users posting the same material at different rates!

Comment: @shmosel Database contains `dog cat animal food pet`. User1 runs the program and starts posting one word from the dB per 10 minutes. User2 opens the program 5 minutes afterwards and begins reading from the same database, posting one word per 5 minutes. The Facebook page, at 20 minutes, contains `dog dog cat cat animal food animal...` Get it?

Comment: Can you add a flag to the entries on the DB to inform that the entry is already processed?